# single potato measurement unit

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

When I need one **loaf** of bread I can easily say so. 
When I need only one [___] potato what would the equivalent word be?

Everything I considered sounds weird. Is there maybe just an old form, not commonly used anymore today? If so, I still would like to know the word ;D

When would it be appropriate to use tubers?

Comment: It's just *one potato*. No unit necessary. Likewise for turnips and tomatoes. If you were after a quantity of the root vegetable, you could ask for *1 kg* of it, or whatever weight you wished to acquire.

Comment: 1 kg is indeed more natural. But what would I say if I start counting them?

Comment: *One potato, two potato, three potato, four; five potato, six potato, seven potato, more* …. (That's the version I remember anyway, but [these lyrics](http://www.songlyrics.com/super-simple-learning/one-potato-two-potatoes-lyrics/) use the more standard plurals.)

Comment: .... In my mother tongue it's possible to say both, no unit as well as the "unit". The unit being a word to describe a big-root-like-thing, also used, and more commonly used for ginger.

Comment: Welcome to English. :)

Comment: I wasn't aware of such a song - made my day :D.

Comment: What is your mother tongue, Marco, is it an East Asian language? I know that Mandarin has units, usually called 'measure words' for everything including the universal 'ge' for all nouns which have no known specific measure word. This is one of the things which English speakers (like me) find awkward when learning Mandarin because English has very few equivalents. There are unit names for uncountable nouns like "water", "sand" and "timber" but the only one I can think of for a countable noun is "head of cattle".

Comment: @BoldBen Interesting, but no it's not. It's swiss-german. In usual "standard" german, which is taught at school, it's exactly the same as in englisch. -> no counting-word. However within the dialect's they can differ. Since you could say 1 erdli, but also 1 herdöpfel (both meaning potato). But if someone would tell me to bring some potatoes and I were to ask how many they could either tell me 1 herdöpfel or 1 knollä. (Knollä literally would be the root - although more commonly used for ginger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just *potato*.

The reason it differs from bread is that *bread* is a mass noun; potatoes are countable (until they're mashed and become a mass noun).

Thus you need to specify a quantity or unit of bread — or any mass noun like water or even mashed potato — but can simply ask for a number of countable potatoes.